# Why I always have invalid view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following view model in my Web Api porject:

```
public class CustomerChangeViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("idfa")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required idfa")]
    public string Idfa { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("idfv")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required idfv")]
    public string Idfv { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("app_build_number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_build_number")]
    public int AppBuildNumber { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("app_version")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_version")]
    public string AppVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("screen_height")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required screen_height")]
    public int ScreenHeight { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("screen_width")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required width")]
    public int ScreenWidth { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("locale")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required locale")]
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("app_id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_id")]
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("app_platform")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_platform")]
    public string AppPlatform { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("manufacturer")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required manufacturer")]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("model")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("os_version")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required os_version")]
    public string OsVersion { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("sdk_version")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required sdk_version")]
    public string SdkVersion { get; set; }
}
```

And the following controller action:

```
    [Route("/v1.0/patch_user")]
    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchUserInfo(CustomerChangeViewModel customerChange)
    { ... }
```

I don't understand where is the mistake, why I always have the following:

[image]

I pin here request body:

```
{
    "Idfa": "lalalal-132-123",
    "idfv": "234234efgsdghnwe5hjqe",
    "app_build_number": 1,
    "app_version": "1.0.0",
    "screen_height": 820,
    "screen_width": 300,
    "locale": "ru",
    "app_id": "com.test",
    "app_platform": "iOS",
    "manufacturer": "Apple",
    "model": "iPhone10,6",
    "os_version": "12.3.1",
    "sdk_version": "0.3"
}
```

I can't understand where is my mistake? Why MVC Framework can't make a map in this case. Thank you for any help!

Comment: How are you sending the data to your API? (JSON? FormData? Other?)

Comment: I'm sanding via HTTP client Insomnia. JSON.

Answer (score 1):

So, it was simple. I just forgot [FromBody]. For JSON request I have to change:

```
[Route("/v1.0/patch_user")]
    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchUserInfo(CustomerChangeViewModel customerChange)
    { ... }
```

to

```
[Route("/v1.0/patch_user")]
    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchUserInfo([FromBody] CustomerChangeViewModel customerChange)
    { ... }
```